# Confusion over Adverbial Adjuncts (X' Bar Theory)

Tags: syntax, x-bar-theory

For my Syntax class this semester, we've been asked to look at a language more in depth and try to develop X-Bar compatible rules for it. In doing so, I've come across a reoccurring problem that may ultimately be a result of a lack of understanding. This problem is how to treat the difference between lexical and affixes that seem to be in the same category in the language when trying to create rules.

For instance, the language I'm looking at is Burmese. In terms of adverbs, there seem to be at least two different types, displayed in the examples below:

[image]
             
             
   [image]

The grammar that I'm referencing classifies both the quickly-quickly adverb and the abruptly suffix as adverbs, so I wasn't sure exactly how to make the X-bar rule as quickly-quickly appears to the left of the verb it's modifying whereas the abruptly suffix appears at the end.

Thank you!

Comment: is 'dou2' element in the second sentence a clitic or a suffix? If it's a clitic it should follow the rules of clitic placement.

Comment: @TsutsuT. it's an onomatopoeic sound so the book just labeled it as dou2 (meaning dull sound)

Comment: Where's the subject in the second sentence? Or which marker implies its existence if it's a pro?